# ExpressJs deepObject parsed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am doing a query with deepObject but some how it is beign parsed incorrectly.

My Query

```
/search?populate%5Bpath%5D=snipeId&populate%5Bmatch%5D%5Brank.value%5Blte%5D%5D=9
```

Which is:

```
{populate[path]: 'snipeId', populate[match][rank.value[lte]]: '9'}
```

Output Value: on backend is shown as :`{ path: 'snipeId', match: { lte: '9' } }`

It should be like this :

```
{ path: 'snipeId', match: { 'rank.value':{lte: '9'} } }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank

Comment: @KonradLinkowski from my understating this should be deepObject: populate[match][rank.value[lte]]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you query.  Is this some kind of database library?

Comment: I didn't know that you could pass nested objects into a query string. Thank you for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
populate[path]=snipeId&populate[match][rank.value][lte]=9
```

instead of

```
populate[path]=snipeId&populate[match][rank.value[lte]]=9
```